# adding components in applet

Tags: java, applet

I am making an applet and as part of my applet, I want this to happen: When the user presses "OK", the old components (some radio buttons) are removed, and a new JPanel is added, with a bunch of textfields.

However, I cannot figure out how to add a new component to the applet after it has started. I made the problem simpler by ignoring the removal part (Which I know how to do) and just adding a simple JLabel instead, but even that won't add!

Here is my code so far:

```
// imports omitted

public class Class extends Applet implements ActionListener 
{
  Button okButton;  
  CheckboxGroup radioGroup; 
  Checkbox radio1; 
  Checkbox radio2; 
  Checkbox radio3;
  JLabel j;

  public void init()  
  { 
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
    okButton = new Button("OK"); 
    j = new JLabel("hello");
    radioGroup = new CheckboxGroup(); 
    radio1 = new Checkbox("Red", radioGroup,false); 
    radio2 = new Checkbox("Blue", radioGroup,true); 
    radio3 = new Checkbox("Green", radioGroup,false); 
    add(okButton); 
    add(radio1); 
    add(radio2); 
    add(radio3);
    okButton.addActionListener(this); 
  }

  public void repaint(Graphics g) 
  { 
    if (radio1.getState()) add(j); 
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)  
  { 
    if (evt.getSource() == okButton) repaint();
  } 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't override the `repaint` method, and certainly not add a component in this method. Just remove the radio buttons from the applet (using its `remove` method) and add the label in the applet in your `actionPerformed` method, the same way you add them in the `init` method.

You might have to call `validate` after.

Answer (score 0):

Add components and then call `validate()` of your container. In this case `yourApplet.validate()`. This will trigger repainting and rearranging of all elements.

Answer (score 0):

**you could do something like**

```
JFrame fr= new JFrame();                    // global variables
JPanel panelToBeAdded = new JPanel();
JPanel initialPanel = new JPanel();
JTextField fieldToBeAdded = new JTextField(); 
panelToBeAdded.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(400,400));
initialPanel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(400,400));
initialPanel.setVisible(true);
fr.add(initialPanel);
fr.setVisible(true);
fr.pack();


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    initialPanel.setVisible(false);
    //radiobuttons.setVisible(false);---> hide the radio buttons
    panelToBeAddedd.add(fieldToBeAddedd);
    panelToBeAddedd.setVisible(true);
    fr.add(panelToBeAddedd);

}

public void repaint( Graphics g ) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

Your `repaint(Graphics)` method is not the same method you are calling in your actionPerformed method.

Also, `repaint` is a pretty bad name for a method which is adding a new component.

```
 public void swapComponents() 
 { 
     if (radio1.getState()) {
        remove(radio1);
        remove(radio2);
        remove(radio3);
        add(j);
        validate();
     }
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)  
 { 
     if (evt.getSource() == okButton) {
        swapComponents();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the user presses "OK", the old components (some radio buttons) are removed, and a new JPanel is added, with a bunch of textfields.

Use a [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005).  It is perfect for situations like this.

[image: Game view]  [image: High Scores view]